# Reenabling Confirmation Dialog for Turning Off Hyper-V VM

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, hyper-v

Normally when you turn off a Hyper-V VM (as opposed to shutting it down), a confirmation dialog appears. This is to prevent you from accidentally switching a machine off. However, for some testing purposes I had disabled this dialog by checking "Don't show this dialog again" option. Now, I want the dialog back. However, I can't find any setting anywhere in Hyper-V to re-enable it. Could you guys suggest where I should look?

Answer (score 2):

Try on Hyper-V Manager → Hyper-V Settings → Reset Check Boxes

[image: Hyper-V Manager - Hyper-V Settings - Reset Check Boxes]

Comment: Thanks! I kept hitting turn off instead of shutdown and I had disabled the confirmation. Turning it on is a life saver.